# Spring Boot @Value Properties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-annotations

I have a Spring Boot application and in one of the classes, I try to reference a property from the application.properties file using `@Value`. But, the property does not get resolved. I have looked at similar posts and tried following the suggestions, but that didn't help. The class is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class PrintProperty {

  @Value("${file.directory}")
  private String fileDirectory;

  public void print() {
    System.out.println(fileDirectory);
  }
}
```

I have the property file.directory in `application.properties`. I have other fields as well.

Comment: Show us the error that you are receiving, Check my answer below it should work.

Comment: I provided the correct answer below. Would appreciate accepted answer :)

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem like you. Here's my error code.

```
@Component
public class GetExprsAndEnvId {
    @Value("hello")
    private String Mysecret;


    public GetExprsAndEnvId() {
        System.out.println("construct");
    }


    public void print(){
        System.out.println(this.Mysecret);
    }


    public String getMysecret() {
        return Mysecret;
    }

    public void setMysecret(String mysecret) {
        Mysecret = mysecret;
    }
}
```

This is no problem like this, but 
we need to use it like this:

```
@Autowired
private GetExprsAndEnvId getExprsAndEnvId;
```

not like this:

```
getExprsAndEnvId = new GetExprsAndEnvId();
```

Here, the field annotated with @Value is null because Spring doesn't know about the copy of GetExprsAndEnvId that is created with new and didn't know to how to inject values in it.

Comment: Thank you! I was having exactly this problem, and this solves it. The weird situation is that Spring does check if the property exists (it throws an error when it's not defined in a properties file), yet it didn't use it to fill the variable. Now it does.

Comment: solved my issue as well, any idea why this happens ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 in short 'Dependency Injection'. You don't create bean objects using `new` operator instead you use the beans created by spring framework using `@Autowired` annotation. When spring application starts up it creates bean and set its fields, now if you don't use this bean and instead use your own object created using `new` operator, you will get null in the property variable.

Answer (score 19):

Make sure your application.properties file is under src/main/resources/application.properties. Is one way to go. Then add @PostConstruct as follows

**Sample Application.properties**

```
file.directory = somePlaceOverHere
```

**Sample Java Class**

```
@ComponentScan
public class PrintProperty {

  @Value("${file.directory}")
  private String fileDirectory;

  @PostConstruct
  public void print() {
    System.out.println(fileDirectory);
  }
}
```

Code above will print out "somePlaceOverhere"

Comment: Using `@PostConstruct` will initialise any fields that depend on the ones initialised by `@Value` annotation. Thanks

Comment: After a lot of research BeanPostProcessors `@PostConstruct` annotation helped to resolve the issue. To read properties from in `@Configuration and @Value`. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I´d like to mention, that I used spring boot version 1.4.0 and since this version you can only write:

```
@Component
public class MongoConnection {

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
private String mongoHost;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.port}")
private int mongoPort;

@Value("${spring.data.mongodb.database}")
private String mongoDB;
}
```

Then inject class whenever you want.

**EDIT:**

From nowadays I would use **@ConfigurationProperties** because you are able to **inject property values in your POJOs**. **Keep hierarchical sort** above your properties. Moreover, **you can put validations** above POJOs attributes and so on. Take a look at the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Why not writing the code directly inside your answer?

Comment: when I am injecting this class to another and accessing each property by getter I am getting NULL

Comment: Why do you need getter ? Are you sure, that there you have properties set in you application.properties ?

Answer (score 2):

To read the values from application.properties we need to just annotate our main class with `@SpringBootApplication` and the class where you are reading with @Component or variety of it. Below is the sample where I have read the values from `application.properties` and it is working fine when web service is invoked. If you deploy the same code as is and try to access from http://localhost:8080/hello you will get the value you have stored in application.properties for the key message.

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    @Value("${message}")
    private String message;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    String home() {
        return message;
    }

}
```

Try and let me know

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. The properties get resolved in my main class with @SpringBootApplication annotation, but not in this class.

Comment: Try adding @Component annotation to your class and let me know what happened

Comment: This code works fine as is for web app. I tried it. But, not works sometimes for standalone app. Not sure what are the reasons for it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included package declarations in the OP but it is possible that neither `@SpringBootApplication` nor `@ComponentScan` are scanning for your `@Component`.

The `@ComponentScan` Javadoc states:

> Either `basePackageClasses` or `basePackages` (or its alias `value`) may be
>   specified to define specific packages to scan. If specific packages
>   are not defined, scanning will occur from the package of the class
>   that declares this annotation.

ISTR wasting a lot of time on this before and found it easiest to simply move my application class to the highest package in my app's package tree.

More recently I encountered a gotcha were the property was being read before the value insertion had been done. Jesse's answer helped as `@PostConstruct` seems to be the earliest you can read the inserted values, and of course you should let Spring call this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue and the above examples doesn't help me to read properties. I have posted the complete class which will help you to read properties values from application.properties file in SpringBoot application in the below link.

[Spring Boot - Environment @Autowired throws NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454289/spring-boot-environment-autowired-throws-nullpointerexception/52054368#52054368)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you need a **`static`** `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` Bean definition in your configuration. I say static with emphasis, because I had a non-static one and it didn't work.

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue get value for my property in my service class. I resolved it by using @ConfigurationProperties instead of @Value.

1. create a class like this:

```
    import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "file")
    public class FileProperties {
        private String directory;

        public String getDirectory() {
            return directory;
        }

        public void setDirectory(String dir) {
            this.directory = dir;
        }
    }
```

2. add the following to your BootApplication class:

```
    @EnableConfigurationProperties({
        FileProperties.class
    })
```

3. Inject FileProperties to your PrintProperty class, then you can get hold of the property through the getter method.