# Passing parameters into Java class from command line

Tags: java, spring

What is the best way of passing parameters into TestConfig.class below? I cannot figure it out.

Calling method like this from command line:

```
com.test.app.Launcher --param.1=test1 --param.2=test2
```

Main method code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(TestConfig.class);
   // ...
}
```

Later on in the program, I want to access the parameters as follows...

```
public class TestConfig {
   
   // how do I access the values in clps here? is this right??

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   private final String PARAM_1 = env.getProperty("param.1");
   private final String PARAM_2 = env.getProperty("param.2");

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use the normal property handling in properties, yaml, environment, command line ?

Comment: It's because I am calling the app from an external source and the parameters passed can vary

Comment: Parameter keys or values ? Boot supports command line passed parameters too: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Comment: `By default SpringApplication will convert any command line option arguments (starting with ‘--’, e.g. --server.port=9000) to a property and add it to the Spring Environment. As mentioned above, command line properties always take precedence over other property sources.` ... this is what I mean. How would I access it from `TestConfig.class` if its a property in the Spring Environment?

Comment: Like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047333/spring-boot-value-properties

Comment: But isn't the example reading from a `application.properties` file, I want to read the command line properties

Comment: I've updated the question... please let me know if its correct

Comment: Have a look at the answer and see how @Value is used. Boot treats .properties and command line parameters the same way, what you are looking for is how to specify where to put the read values

Answer (score 0):

Like can be seen on several [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047333/spring-boot-value-properties)s here on stack overflow you can use `@Value` to "import" values:

```
@Value("${my.param}")
private String param;
```

These parameters can come from several sources, command line parameters in the shape of `-D` and [real command line parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args) are one. See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) for a list of supported sources.