# How to access a property passed by command line in Spring Boot

Tags: spring

In our environment, the port the server listens is always specified by a command line parameter:

`java -jar myweb.jar --server.port=1024`.

How can we get this value? In my `AppSiteController.java` I tried to use:

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private static String serverPort;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(serverPort);
    SpringApplication.run(AppSiteController.class, args);
}
```

Which returns null when the value is correctly specified on the command line.

Thanks.

Comment: your code is correct. only problem is how you are passing the argument. Check out the answer from Essex Boy.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot 2.x, you can override system properties like below:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--server.port=8085
```

By default,Spring Boot converts command-line arguments to properties and adds them as environment variables.

You can access command line argument from application's main method as:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(String arg:args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This will print the arguments we passed to our application from command-line.

Comment: Your suggestion worked 100%. My working code in `main()` is this: `for(String arg:args) { if (arg.startsWith("---server.port=")) System.out.println(arg.substring(15));}` However, it is not as elegant as `@Value` which doesn't work for me.

Comment: I think, it should work for your code. Did you try with @Value annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Pass it as a system parameter to the jvm

```
java -Dserver.port=8080 -jar spring-boot.jar
```

All java system parameters are added to the spring environment

Comment: Your command did not have an effect; `java -jar spring-boot.jar --server.port=8080` has an effect, but it produces 'null' in the said `main()` ...

Comment: @user55305 sorry I put the java parameter in the wrong place, needs to come after the java command, have corrected answer

Answer (score 0):

rather than using

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private static String serverPort;
```

consider using below in springboot application :

```
@Bean
    public String value(@Value("#{server.port}")String value){
        return value;
    }
```

And then access value as

```
SpringApplication.run(AppSiteController.class, args).getBean("value");
```

and pass in command line

```
-Dserver.port=...
```

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I found that it is because Spring boot can't inject value into static variables. The solution is here:

[Spring Boot @Value Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047333/spring-boot-value-properties)

This code:

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private static String serverPort;
```

Should be this:

```
private static String serverPort;
@Value("${server.port}")
public void setPort(String value) {
    serverPort = value;
}
```

Comment: there's not point in doing this, the spring class is a singleton anyway, don't use the static, just have a class that's only used to wire values.