# Spring Boot property source not used at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a very small Spring Boot program that attempts to add its own properties in the relevant class

```
package com.findology.testboot2;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Configuration
@PropertySource({ /*"classpath:/application.properties",*/ "classpath:/countrycounts.properties" })
@Component
public class CountryCountsWebSetup implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory> {

@Value("${countrycounts.server.port}")
int port;

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory server) {
        server.setPort(port);
    }

}
```

and a properties file

> countrycounts.kafka.bootstrapServers=
>   kafka1.data.int.dc1.ad.net:9092,kafka2.data.int.dc1.ad.net:9092,kafka3.data.int.dc1.ad.net:9092,kafka4.data.int.dc1.ad.net:9092,kafka5.data.int.dc1.ad.net:9092
>
> countrycounts.kafka.topic= COUNTRY_COUNTS_WINDOWS
>
> countrycounts.kafka.listener.id= country_counts_window
>
> countrycounts.server.port= 8989

The problem I'm having is that while running with debug turned on Spring Boot appears to find and load the `countrycounts.properties` file

`2018-08-29 17:14:10.697 [main; MutablePropertySources] DEBUG -- Adding PropertySource 'class path resource [countrycounts.properties]' with search precedence immediately higher than 'class path resource [f2-traffic.properties]'`

but cannot complete startup because it claims the `countrycounts.server.port` property is missing.

`2018-08-29 17:14:12.705 [main; AbstractApplicationContext] WARN  -- Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JettyServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedJetty.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryCountsWebSetup': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'countrycounts.server.port' in value "${countrycounts.server.port}"`

If I set the value on the java command line using `-D`, it works fine but still implies that the property was not read from the file.

Any ideas why the property file gets loaded but the values within are not used?

**UPDATE**

As part of the maven dependencies for this program, a large (and complicated) jar file is included which uses Spring 4.1 and includes a `propertyPlaceHolder` and it also defines `location`.  Could that be destroying the path to the properties file I need thus causing those properties not to be seen?

Comment: Why are you not leveraging spring-boot's property configuration? why do you have two properties files and mapping them manually?

Comment: most probably the issue is how you are mapping the countrycounts.properties , also does the f2-traffic.properties contain the same value as well ? ? check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39047333/spring-boot-value-properties) as well

Comment: @AmitPhaltankar I tried putting the property values in `application.properties` and let them be loaded automatically but that did not work either

Comment: @AntJavaDev The properties I'm using only exist in the `countrycounts.properties` file so there are no overrides.  Could you explain more about what you mean by _mapping the countrycounts.properties_
Regarding the answer you referred, I tried all of those and none of them seemed to work.

Comment: With mapping the properties i meant on how you are referring to the file and whether if that is available on your classpath during runtime. I am guessing that you are creating a runnable jar(Spring boot app) so if you could double check that all the files are properly packaged inside the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue but not in a very clean way.  I don't like the solution but it seems to work.

To resolve it I extracted the embedded properties defining xml file from the jar file dependency.  I then removed the `placeholderProperties` from it and created a new file with a new placeholderProperties that pointed to my directories.  That was followed by adding a `ImportSource` to my new xml file and making sure the class which used the large jar file explicitly included the copied and modified property/xml files it needed.

At that point, my properties were seen and everything ran fine *but* I think this is a big kludge and I would still like to find a real Spring Boot way to do this cleanly.