# Reading Value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am not familiar with Java Spring. I am trying to fix a small bug in a Spring Boot code another developer has written. I can't seem to find a proper way to read a value I newly defined in application.properties. However, the code uses other values defined in application.properties; only that, even if I use the same syntax the other developer has used, still I can't read the value.

Here's what I've already tried:

**read from environment:**

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

public class MyClass {
    String myVar;

    public MyClass(String a, boolean b, Environment environment) {
         this.myVar = environment.getProperty("property.to.read");
    }

}
```

**@Value**

```
@Autowired
public class MyClass {
    String myVar;

    public MyClass(String a, boolean b, @Value("${property.to.read}") String c) {
         this.myVar = c;
    }

}
```

On both these occasions, myVar end up reporting null. Is there another configuration like an XML entry I need to add to get this to work? I have no Spring knowledge (I am not an experienced Java developer also, only trying to fix a bug in the code).

Comment: Is the `application.properties` file in the correct location? It should be under the `src/main/resources` folder.

Comment: Yes application.properties is at the right place

Answer (score 2):

Try to `Autowire` the `Environment` and then fetch the property .
I have just extended your example by  adding the `@Autowired` dependency.

```
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

public class MyClass {
    String myVar;

@Autowired
private Environment env;

    public CalibrateJob(String a, boolean b) {
         this.myVar = env.getProperty("property.to.read");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting a NullPointerException. Intellij complaints env is not initialized. Also, I am trying to use env in the constructor of the class.

Comment: Check this out once , it looks like its getting initialized early hence throwing nullpointer.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/19454289/6309111

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to declare the value like this. The "resource.path" is the key value inside the application.properties.

```
   @Value("${resource.path}")
        private String resourcePath;
```